# Почему не сохраняется глагольный суффикс в причастии?

Tags: орфография, причастия

Мы пишем:  выровнЯть - выровнЕнный, приравнЯть - приравнЕнный, глагольный суффикс Я не сохраняется. Но: подстрелИть - подстрелЕнный, пристрелЯть - пристрелЯнный.

Например: Стена под плитку должна быть обязательно  выровненной. Местности, приравненные к районам Крайнего Севера.Французские пушки били по пристрелянным позициям. В подстреленной птичке я признал сыча.

Comment: Словообразовательный словарь Тихонова рассматривает образование  прилагательного-причастия ВЫРОВНЕННЫЙ как образование от глагола ВЫРОВНИТЬ, то есть используется суффикс    -ЕНН- , как во всех глаголах   на -ИТЬ (подаренный, засоренный и т.п.)   ПРИРАВНЕННЫЙ же у Тихонова и вовсе отсутствует...

Comment: У меня есть старый словарь Тихонова (1978 года), но там дается: ровный – ровнять – выровнять .  В словарях глагола  «выровнить» нет. В то же время причастия «выровненный, приравненный» с суффиксом ЕНН смотрятся нормально, суффикс Я+НН в них как-то неуместен. Возможно, суффикс ЕНН соответствует глагольному суффиксу И со значением совершенного вида, а суффикс Я  в этом случае связывается с видом несовершенным и поэтому не пишется.  Но вот что интересно: обращают ли на это внимание школьники и как им эта тема объясняется.

Comment: Вера, мне кажется, что школьником такие нюансы не объясняют. Зачем им голову пудрить?! Может, в лингвистических школах объясняют.

Answer (score 1):

По моему мнению, тут дело в логике языка и утрате (или намеренном исключении) некоторых языковых форм. У младших школьников, как раз, с этим проблем нет. Совершенный вид: выровнить, приравнить несовершенный вид: выровнЯть (то же, что и выравнивать), прировнЯть  - с ударением на Я. Отсюда и образование причастий совершенного вида. Но язык меняется, что-то уходит... . По поводу стрельбы... тут можно и пристрелять и пристрелить (возможно были те же варианты и с иными приставками). Сравните: "Враг, пристреленный командиром" и "Пушки били по пристрелянным позициям". И еще интересный факт. Малышами мы играли в индейцев. Когда кто-то целился в моего товарища СТРЕЛОЙ из лука, он говорил: "Не надо меня стрелить".

Comment: Глагола *выровнить* в литературном русском нет. *Выровнять* (сов. в.) не то же, что *выравнивать* (несов. в.). И зачем нам "интересный факт", позвольте узнать? Чем он полезен?