# Обменянный или обмененный?

Tags: грамматика

Правильно: обменянный, об этом говорится в словарях, эта форма указана   в парадигме Зализняка для глагола "обменять". Но почему в произведениях известных писателей мы встречаем форму "обмененный"?

Например: Сергей уехал на лето на какие-то строительные работы и доверил любимому учителю свое бесценное сокровище ― мотоцикл, **обмененный** на выигранный по лотерее холодильник... [И. А. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы (1959-1963)]

[обмененный | ruscorpora.ru](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%E1%EC%E5%ED%E5%ED%ED%FB%E9)

А вот для глагола "выровнять" используется форма "выровненный", а почему? Почему написание "...нянный" кажется некорректным? Есть ли связь между этими двумя примерами?

Comment: Про "выровнять" здесь:[Почему не сохраняется глагольный суффикс в причастии?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31832/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ОБМЕНИ́ТЬ** -меню́, -ме́нишь; **обменённый**; -нён, -нена́, -нено́; св. *что*. *Разг.*
**1.** = Обменя́ть.
Обменить деньги. Обменить документы.
**2.** Подменить, ошибочно или умышленно взять чужую вещь вместо своей.
*Кто-то **обменил** мой зонтик. В гардеробе ему **обменили** пальто на чьё-то старое.*
[**Энциклопедический словарь**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/119494)

Приставка **об-** привносит в глагол **менить** значение направленности действия в ущерб тому, для кого оно производится.
***Менить - обменить - обменивать:***
ошибочно или с умыслом брать чужую вещь, обычно более ценную.
(*Когда расходились, …кто-то обменил хорошую поддевку на старую.* Чехов.)

Лучше, чем отражено в книге [***Варианты приставочных глаголов несовершенного вида в русском языке***](https://books.google.ee/books?id=6QnS9nTXdyQC&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=HXtEuNlQvj&sig=iLkiBnPSndi6V6xA3OJtbHTElM0&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8tZiPsbbVAhXjA5oKHTx2D6UQ6AEIajAJ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false), я не смогу сказать.

Попытаюсь сделать вывод: оба варианта правильны — *обмен**я**нный или обмен**ё**нный* — взависимости от контекста и смысла.
[**Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку, *"обменить"***](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/40216)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Удивительно то, что я этот глагол никогда не слышала, стрванно, что он не относится к устаревшим. В Нацкорпусе форма "обменил"  последний раз встречается в 1937 году.

Comment: _В Грязях обменил билет и продолжал путь уже полноправным пассажиром. Всю ночь спокойно спал на второй лавочке._ / _Когда он неловко и медленно поворачивал шею, посадский быстро обменил ковши – Сенькин себе, свой – ему._ / _Ведь не станете ж вы здесь меня уверять, что вам было б совсем безразлично, если бы какой-нибудь встречный хулиган насильно обменил вашу каракулевую шапку на свой засаленный малахай._ / _... что ночной его гость, уехав рано утром, обменил своего неподкованного и заморенного коня на лучшую лошадь, какая только была в эспионьольских конюшнях..._